# How to reduce spacing between figure and text

Tags: spacing, floats, revtex

I want to reduce spacing between figure and text (not caption) and between paragraphs. I'm using revtex4 package (two column style).

Comment: The reason TeX inserts more vertical space here is to avoid having the very start of a paragraph (first two lines or so) separated from the rest of the paragraph. It's part of the page breaking algorithm, I believe. I would reconsider if you actually want this...

Answer (score 3):

To reduce the spacing between figures and text, you can use `\belowcaptionskip` if all your figures have a `\caption`:

```
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{-3ex}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    Figure contents
    \caption{Figure caption}
\end{figure}
```

In order to reduce the spacing between paragraphs, set `\parskip`:

```
\setlength{\parskip}{0mm}
```

To see the current value, use `\the\parskip` (displayed in document) or `\showthe\parskip` (displayed in latex output).

Comment: It does work for paragraphs, but not for figures. I'm having few figures and text between them in two column paper, but figure-text spacing is quite irregular.

Comment: Try also setting `textfloasep=20pt`, set to 0pt first to see difference.

Comment: `\belowcaptionskip` obviously only works if you have a `\caption`.